# Use a table or flexbox to create a grid-like UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, flexbox

I need to create an grid-like UI with rows and columns.
The main requirement is that the column and rows adapt to the cell contents.
For example column 1 has the width of the text placed in the cell at row1,column1.
The height of row 1 is the height of the cell at row1,column2.

The cell content is text and radio buttons.

Can I do this with flex-box or just with good old table?
Any examples?

With flexbox I think I will need to have nested flexboxes? not sure.

[image]

Comment: Seems like simple tables should do. Do you have an example when you tried and it didn't work?

Comment: The information you're presenting would appear to be tabular, so using a table to present it makes semantic sense, and also behaves the way you've described in browsers. Is there some reason you don't think you should use a table? Is the information *not* semantically a table?

Comment: Can you use CSS Grid Layout here?

Comment: CSS Grid is not in available in IE11. Polyfills might exist but I haven't tried any. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** the information you're presenting is really tabular, semantically, then using a table makes sense because it fits the information you're presenting and works the way you've said you want it to in browsers.

E.g.:

```css
.target, .target td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.special {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="target">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Column width is width of this text</td>
      <td class="special">Row height is height of this text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: You have one "special" cell that has centered text rather than left-justified text; I've used a `special` class on it above.

---

If the information **isn't** tabular, semantically, you can use other kinds of elements to present it and adapt their display characteristics with CSS to get the presentation you want. In particular, [all vaguely-modern browsers support](http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell) the use of `display: table`, `display: table-row`, and `display: table-cell`.
E.g.:

```css
.target {
  display: table;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.target, .target .cell {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.special {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="target">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Column width is width of this text</div>
    <div class="cell special">Row height is height of this text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Text</div>
    <div class="cell">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There I've used `row` and `cell` classes, but you could also use structural selectors.

Comment: Thank you. To answer your question from the comment: The actual formation is tabular, like in the example. The reason I thought not to use table is because I've read "tables are bad". But I guess in this case, it actually makes sense, the data is tabular.

Comment: I will check today how tables work for what I am trying to do.

Comment: @DonBox: "Tables are bad" was always an overblown statement. But it was "tables *for layout* are bad." E.g., using a table when the contents *weren't* a table semantically. Using tables for content that's semantically a table is what tables are for. :-)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, "tables are bad for LAYOUT" indeed.